# CSV to multilevel/nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I want to convert a `csv` to multilevel `json`. All I want is from:

```
brand,  active, prod   , prod_id, part, part_id, part_prise
canon,  1     , camera , 132    , body,  543   , 399
canon,  0     , camera , 132    , lens,  543   , 399
canon,  1     , printer, 132    , cart,  543   , 399
canon,  1     , printer, 872    , ink ,  543   , 399
sony ,  1     , camera , 132    , body,  543   , 399
sony ,  1     , lcd    , 112    , body,  543   , 399
sony ,  0     , lcd    , 132    , body,  543   , 399
sony ,  1     , laptop , 162    , body,  543   , 399
```

And following should be its JSON file.

```
brand : "canon",
active : 1,
prod : [{
     prod : "camera",
     prod_id : 132,
     part : [{
            part : "body",
            part_id : 543,
            part_prise:399
            },
           {
            part : "lens",
            part_id : 543,
            part_prise:399
            }]
         },{
     prod : "printer",
     prod_id : 132,
     part : [{
            part : "cart",
            part_id : 543,
            part_prise:399
            },
           {
            part : "ink",
            part_id : 543,
            part_prise:399
            }]
         }
      ]
...
...
...and so on..
```

Comment: can you show the php or javascript that you are using to convert it ?

Comment: I'm looking for solution.. realy i don't have any file..  whatever i start.. i just quit.. simultaniously my brain start thinking to quickly and so many thing.. and become de-tracked..

Comment: Is just a bit confusing since you said *trying to resolve this for about a week*,  and there is like 100 questions here in how to do it in javascript or php..

Comment: but i'm looking in javascript.. the client want to run this all locallay..also can you please suggest me any in php...?

Comment: your tag says JavaScript.. something like this could do with some modifications ... good luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096509/php-convert-csv-to-specific-json-format

Comment: thank you for the tip. let me play with it.. i'll update here in either case ..

Comment: no.. i couldn't get anything from it. here is the code i've created so far. but i want them to stay interlinked.. as i illustrator above..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mfarooqi/4Nsqd/1/

Answer (score 1):

use csv dictreader, it prescent in the python csv package