# converting a csv file to json + python with specific json format

Tags: python, json, csv

can I convert a csv file into json as follows:
csv = headers in line1 with values below 
json = `[{"key1":"value1",...},{"key1":"value2",...}...]`

This is my csv file:

```
$ cat -v head_data.csv
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description"
"2016-05-30","686","230","63979","Samsung SM-G935FD ","Samsung SM-G935FD","$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"
"2016-05-30","533","970","171631866","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","iPhone 6 (A1586)","$69.95 Plan"
"2016-05-30","191","610","145713","Samsung GT-I9195","Samsung GT-I9195","$29.95 Plan"
"2016-05-30","660","660","2994742","Samsung SM-N920I","Samsung SM-N920I","GOVERNMENT TIER 2 PLAN"
"2016-05-30","182","970","37799939","Samsung SM-J200Y","Samsung SM-J200Y","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2016-05-30","993","360","14096114","Samsung SM-A300Y","Samsung SM-A300Y","$39.95 Carryover Plan"
"2016-05-30","894","730","9851177","Samsung GT-N7105","Samsung GT-N7105","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"
"2016-05-30","600","070","18420650","Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)","Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2016-05-30","234","000","1769661","Galaxy S7 SM-G930F ","Galaxy S7 SM-G930F","$39.95 Plan"
```

This is my script:

```
$ cat csv_to_json.py

#!/usr/bin/python

#from here
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550352/2392358

import csv, json
csvreader = csv.reader(open('head_data.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t',
quotechar='"')
data = []
for row in csvreader:
    r = []
    for field in row:
        if field == '': field = None
        else: field = unicode(field, 'ISO-8859-1')
        r.append(field)
    data.append(r)
jsonStruct = {
    'header': data[0],
    'data': data[1:]
}
open('head_data.json', 'wb').write(json.dumps(jsonStruct))
```

Runnning my script and output

```
$ python csv_to_json.py


$ cat -v head_data.json
{"header": ["Rec Open Date,\"MSISDN\",\"IMEI\",\"Data Volume (Bytes)\",\"Device Manufacturer\",\"Device Model\",\"Product Description\""], "data": [["2016-05-30,\"686\",\"230\",\"63979\",\"Samsung SM-G935FD \",\"Samsung SM-G935FD\",\"$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)\""], ["2016-05-30,\"533\",\"970\",\"171631866\",\"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)\",\"iPhone 6 (A1586)\",\"$69.95 Plan\""], ["2016-05-30,\"191\",\"610\",\"145713\",\"Samsung GT-I9195\",\"Samsung GT-I9195\",\"$29.95 Plan\""], ["2016-05-30,\"660\",\"660\",\"2994742\",\"Samsung SM-N920I\",\"Samsung SM-N920I\",\"GOVERNMENT TIER 2 PLAN\""], ["2016-05-30,\"182\",\"970\",\"37799939\",\"Samsung SM-J200Y\",\"Samsung SM-J200Y\",\"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -\""], ["2016-05-30,\"993\",\"360\",\"14096114\",\"Samsung SM-A300Y\",\"Samsung SM-A300Y\",\"$39.95 Carryover Plan\""], ["2016-05-30,\"894\",\"730\",\"9851177\",\"Samsung GT-N7105\",\"Samsung GT-N7105\",\"PREPAY STD - $0 - #2\""], ["2016-05-30,\"600\",\"070\",\"18420650\",\"Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)\",\"Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)\",\"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -\""], ["2016-05-30,\"234\",\"000\",\"1769661\",\"Galaxy S7 SM-G930F \",\"Galaxy S7 SM-G930F\",\"$39.95 Plan\""]]}
```

**Can i slightly modify the code so that I can get output like this:**

```
[{"Rec Open Date":"2016-07-03","MSISDN":540,"IMEI":990,"Data Volume (Bytes)":36671453,"Device Manufacturer":"HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","Device Model":"H1512","Product Description":"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"},
{"Rec Open Date":"2016-07-03","MSISDN":334,"IMEI":340,"Data Volume (Bytes)":129835114,"Device Manufacturer":"Apple Inc","Device Model":"Apple iPhone S (A1530)","Product Description":"$29.95 Plan"},
{"Rec Open Date":"2016-07-03","MSISDN":133,"IMEI":870,"Data Volume (Bytes)":42213030,"Device Manufacturer":"Apple Inc","Device Model":"Apple iPhone 6 Plus (A1524)","Product Description":"$49.95 Plan"}]
```

related Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933914/how-to-convert-specific-csv-format-to-json-using-python)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096509/php-convert-csv-to-specific-json-format)

**edit1** found this [here](http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) but this does the conversion in the browser and I think it uses js.

### EDIT2 - based on the answer below this is what I want

This is the file I want to convert

```
$ cat -v head_data.csv
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description"
"2016-05-30","686","230","63979","Samsung SM-G935FD ","Samsung,A, SM-G935FD","$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"
"2016-05-30","533","970","171631866","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","iPhone 6 (A1586)","$69.95 Plan"
"2016-05-30","191","610","145713","Samsung GT-I9195","Samsung GT-I9195","$29.95 Plan"
"2016-05-30","660","660","2994742","Samsung SM-N920I","Samsung SM-N920I","GOVERNMENT TIER 2 PLAN"
"2016-05-30","182","970","37799939","Samsung SM-J200Y","Samsung SM-J200Y","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2016-05-30","993","360","14096114","Samsung SM-A300Y","Samsung SM-A300Y","$39.95 Carryover Plan"
"2016-05-30","894","730","9851177","Samsung GT-N7105","Samsung GT-N7105","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"
"2016-05-30","600","070","18420650","Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)","Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2016-05-30","234","000","1769661","Galaxy S7 SM-G930F ","Galaxy S7 SM-G930F","$39.95 Plan"
```

This is the script:

```
$ cat -v csv_to_json2.py
#!/usr/bin/python

#from here
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/38193687/2392358

import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

dR=csv.DictReader(open("head_data.csv"))
oD=[ OrderedDict(
         sorted(dct.iteritems(),
                key=lambda item:dR.fieldnames.index(item[0])))
     for dct in dR ]

#print to terminal
print json.dumps(oD)

#write to file
#json.dump(oD,"head_op.json")
open('head_op.json', 'wb').write(json.dumps(oD))
```

Running the script:

```
$ python csv_to_json2.py
[{"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "686", "IMEI": "230", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "63979", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-G935FD ", "Device Model": "Samsung,A, SM-G935FD", "Product Description": "$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "533", "IMEI": "970", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "171631866", "Device Manufacturer": "Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)", "Device Model": "iPhone 6 (A1586)", "Product Description": "$69.95 Plan"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "191", "IMEI": "610", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "145713", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung GT-I9195", "Device Model": "Samsung GT-I9195", "Product Description": "$29.95 Plan"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "660", "IMEI": "660", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "2994742", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-N920I", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-N920I", "Product Description": "GOVERNMENT TIER 2 PLAN"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "182", "IMEI": "970", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "37799939", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-J200Y", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-J200Y", "Product Description": "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "993", "IMEI": "360", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "14096114", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-A300Y", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-A300Y", "Product Description": "$39.95 Carryover Plan"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "894", "IMEI": "730", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "9851177", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung GT-N7105", "Device Model": "Samsung GT-N7105", "Product Description": "PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "600", "IMEI": "070", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "18420650", "Device Manufacturer": "Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)", "Device Model": "Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)", "Product Description": "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "234", "IMEI": "000", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "1769661", "Device Manufacturer": "Galaxy S7 SM-G930F ", "Device Model": "Galaxy S7 SM-G930F", "Product Description": "$39.95 Plan"}]
```

This is the output:

```
$ cat -v head_op.json
[{"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "686", "IMEI": "230", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "63979", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-G935FD ", "Device Model": "Samsung,A, SM-G935FD", "Product Description": "$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "533", "IMEI": "970", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "171631866", "Device Manufacturer": "Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)", "Device Model": "iPhone 6 (A1586)", "Product Description": "$69.95 Plan"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "191", "IMEI": "610", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "145713", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung GT-I9195", "Device Model": "Samsung GT-I9195", "Product Description": "$29.95 Plan"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "660", "IMEI": "660", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "2994742", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-N920I", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-N920I", "Product Description": "GOVERNMENT TIER 2 PLAN"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "182", "IMEI": "970", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "37799939", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-J200Y", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-J200Y", "Product Description": "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "993", "IMEI": "360", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "14096114", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-A300Y", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-A300Y", "Product Description": "$39.95 Carryover Plan"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "894", "IMEI": "730", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "9851177", "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung GT-N7105", "Device Model": "Samsung GT-N7105", "Product Description": "PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "600", "IMEI": "070", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "18420650", "Device Manufacturer": "Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)", "Device Model": "Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)", "Product Description": "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"}, {"Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30", "MSISDN": "234", "IMEI": "000", "Data Volume (Bytes)": "1769661", "Device Manufacturer": "Galaxy S7 SM-G930F ", "Device Model": "Galaxy S7 SM-G930F", "Product Description": "$39.95 Plan"}]
```

Comment: I'd rather define a class with specific properly named member for each field in the row and then serialize it to JSON using the default JSON serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about key's order, just do:

```
import csv
import json
json.dumps(list(csv.DictReader(open("file.csv"))))
```

Check [pretty printing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) section on the manual for more options, or do

```
json.dumps(list( csv.DictReader(open("file.csv")) ])).replace("}, ","},\n")
```

To get your expected output.

---

If you want ordered printing, you may order the keys via OrderedDict:

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

dR=csv.DictReader(open("/tmp/ah.csv"))
oD=[ OrderedDict(
         sorted(dct.iteritems(),
                key=lambda item:dR.fieldnames.index(item[0])))
     for dct in dR ]
json.dumps(oD)
```

Comment: tks but I am having trouble piecing all that together. how do I write it to an output file?

Comment: `json.dumps()` output is an string. Use `file.write()` to save it. An example is in the last line of the script on your question.

Comment: tks, I would like the key order to be the same as the csv, is this possible?

Comment: A: use `json.dump(obj, file)` to write the json directly to a file, and B: both `dump` and `dumps` [have a `sort_keys` option](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html?highlight=sort_keys)

Comment: **C**: list comprehension is not needed here, just `list(csv.DictReader(...))` would do, **D**:  _do not_ do `.replace("}, ","},\n")`, if a string contained `}, ` then a newline would be inserted into that string and it would corrupt the data.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen A: I don't know if it's possible to only insert line breaks between json objects without post processing the string. B: That sort is only alphabetical, I  couldn't find how to provide a lambda.

Comment: A custom `JSONEncoder` may be the proper way to handle B&D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the order of the keys, don't use `csv.DictReader` since it overcomplicates things, just record the header and then `zip` it with each of the rows:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
reader = csv.reader(open("text.csv"))

header = next(reader)

data = [OrderedDict(zip(header,fields)) for fields in reader]
```

Then you can write it to a file with this:

```
import json

with open("new.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative command line solution:

1. Install dependencies:

```sh
pip install pyexcel-cli pyexcel-text
```

2. Run the following command to transform csv to json

```sh
pyexcel transcode --name-columns-by-row 0 --output-file-type json example.csv -
```

output:

```
{"example.csv": [{"Data Volume (Bytes)": 63979, "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-G935FD ", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-G935FD", "IMEI": 230, "MSISDN": 686, "Product Description": "$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}, {"Data Volume (Bytes)": 171631866, "Device Manufacturer": "Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)", "Device Model": "iPhone 6 (A1586)", "IMEI": 970, "MSISDN": 533, "Product Description": "$69.95 Plan", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}, {"Data Volume (Bytes)": 145713, "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung GT-I9195", "Device Model": "Samsung GT-I9195", "IMEI": 610, "MSISDN": 191, "Product Description": "$29.95 Plan", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}, {"Data Volume (Bytes)": 2994742, "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-N920I", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-N920I", "IMEI": 660, "MSISDN": 660, "Product Description": "GOVERNMENT TIER 2 PLAN", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}, {"Data Volume (Bytes)": 37799939, "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-J200Y", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-J200Y", "IMEI": 970, "MSISDN": 182, "Product Description": "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}, {"Data Volume (Bytes)": 14096114, "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung SM-A300Y", "Device Model": "Samsung SM-A300Y", "IMEI": 360, "MSISDN": 993, "Product Description": "$39.95 Carryover Plan", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}, {"Data Volume (Bytes)": 9851177, "Device Manufacturer": "Samsung GT-N7105", "Device Model": "Samsung GT-N7105", "IMEI": 730, "MSISDN": 894, "Product Description": "PREPAY STD - $0 - #2", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}, {"Data Volume (Bytes)": 18420650, "Device Manufacturer": "Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)", "Device Model": "Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)", "IMEI": "070", "MSISDN": 600, "Product Description": "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}, {"Data Volume (Bytes)": 1769661, "Device Manufacturer": "Galaxy S7 SM-G930F ", "Device Model": "Galaxy S7 SM-G930F", "IMEI": "000", "MSISDN": 234, "Product Description": "$39.95 Plan", "Rec Open Date": "2016-05-30"}]}
```

Comment: Tried this solution, yet did not get the same output as stated by the author.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` library was the easiest for me.

1. Install dependencies

```sh
pip install pandas
```

2. Create your csv to json script (let's call it `csv2json.py`)

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
data_frame.to_json(sys.argv[1].replace('.csv', '.json'), orient='records', indent=2)
```

3. Run the `csv2json.py` script on an `example.csv` file input

```sh
python csv2json.py example.csv
```

4. Your json has been generated in `example.json` file

---

**Example:**

input (`example.csv`):

```
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description"
"2016-05-30","686","230","63979","Samsung SM-G935FD ","Samsung SM-G935FD","$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"
"2016-05-30","533","970","171631866","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","iPhone 6 (A1586)","$69.95 Plan"
"2016-05-30","191","610","145713","Samsung GT-I9195","Samsung GT-I9195","$29.95 Plan"
"2016-05-30","660","660","2994742","Samsung SM-N920I","Samsung SM-N920I","GOVERNMENT TIER 2 PLAN"
"2016-05-30","182","970","37799939","Samsung SM-J200Y","Samsung SM-J200Y","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2016-05-30","993","360","14096114","Samsung SM-A300Y","Samsung SM-A300Y","$39.95 Carryover Plan"
"2016-05-30","894","730","9851177","Samsung GT-N7105","Samsung GT-N7105","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"
"2016-05-30","600","070","18420650","Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)","Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2016-05-30","234","000","1769661","Galaxy S7 SM-G930F ","Galaxy S7 SM-G930F","$39.95 Plan"
```

output (`example.json`):

```
[
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":686,
    "IMEI":230,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":63979,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Samsung SM-G935FD ",
    "Device Model":"Samsung SM-G935FD",
    "Product Description":"$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"
  },
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":533,
    "IMEI":970,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":171631866,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)",
    "Device Model":"iPhone 6 (A1586)",
    "Product Description":"$69.95 Plan"
  },
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":191,
    "IMEI":610,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":145713,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Samsung GT-I9195",
    "Device Model":"Samsung GT-I9195",
    "Product Description":"$29.95 Plan"
  },
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":660,
    "IMEI":660,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":2994742,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Samsung SM-N920I",
    "Device Model":"Samsung SM-N920I",
    "Product Description":"GOVERNMENT TIER 2 PLAN"
  },
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":182,
    "IMEI":970,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":37799939,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Samsung SM-J200Y",
    "Device Model":"Samsung SM-J200Y",
    "Product Description":"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
  },
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":993,
    "IMEI":360,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":14096114,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Samsung SM-A300Y",
    "Device Model":"Samsung SM-A300Y",
    "Product Description":"$39.95 Carryover Plan"
  },
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":894,
    "IMEI":730,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":9851177,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Samsung GT-N7105",
    "Device Model":"Samsung GT-N7105",
    "Product Description":"PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"
  },
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":600,
    "IMEI":70,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":18420650,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)",
    "Device Model":"Apple iPhone 5C (A1529)",
    "Product Description":"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
  },
  {
    "Rec Open Date":"2016-05-30",
    "MSISDN":234,
    "IMEI":0,
    "Data Volume (Bytes)":1769661,
    "Device Manufacturer":"Galaxy S7 SM-G930F ",
    "Device Model":"Galaxy S7 SM-G930F",
    "Product Description":"$39.95 Plan"
  }
]
```